# Can't figure out how to get Blueprint.NET to work with OrientDB. Anyone else get it to work?

Tags: c#, orientdb

I have been trying to use [Blueprint.NET](https://github.com/ahzf/Blueprints.NET), which is supposed to be a C# implementation of Tinkerpop, to access [OrientDB](http://code.google.com/p/orient/).  I've been scouring the website and emailed the developer but have been unable to figure out anyway to connect them.  I've used some REST code to connect to OrientDB, but it doesn't seem to have the speed that everyone says it should.  I'd like to try Blueprint.NET to see if it would be faster.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I actually just gave up on this.  I decided to go with MongoDB instead. Bigger community, better support, excellent speed. :)

Answer (score 0):

What kind of problems do you have? You could also use the OrientDB C driver.